# How can I improve performance processing stream that is filtered based on other stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm facing a performance problem while processing a big stream of objects (from one source) that is being filtered and mapped with values from another big stream/collection (suppose from a different source). I'm trying to do a kind of Join (sql).

My machine is taking 11+ minutes to execute it.

I have tried added a filter before to the map, but it degraded more the situation.

What could I do on this matter to get better results?

I'm going to provide an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Note that the filter is using just the ID, but could be used more common properties of both streams.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ProcessorQuestion {

  static record Element(int id, String content) {

    public Element(int id, String content) {
      this.id = id;
      this.content = content == null ? "Data " + id : content;
    }
  }

  static record Row(int id, String content) {

    public Row(int id, String content) {
      this.id = id;
      this.content = content == null ? "Row " + id : content;
    }
  }

  static record RowVsElement(Row row, Element element) {
  }

  private static Random r = new Random();

  protected static Stream<Element> loadElementsData() {
    return IntStream.range(1, 1_000_000)
                    .mapToObj(value -> new Element(r.nextInt(235_000), null));
  }

  protected static Stream<Row> loadRowsData() {
    return IntStream.range(1, 235_000)
                    .mapToObj(value -> new Row(r.nextInt(235_000), null));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    var init = Instant.now();

    final ProcessorQuestion processor = new ProcessorQuestion(loadElementsData());
    processor.process();

    System.err.println("Runned in " + Duration.between(init, Instant.now()).toMinutes() + " min");

  }

  private final Collection<Element> entries;

  public ProcessorQuestion(Stream<Element> entries) {
    this.entries = entries.collect(toSet());
  }

  void process() {
    //    System.out.println("rows size = " + rows.size());
    System.out.println("elements size = " + entries.size());

    loadRowsData().parallel()
                  //                    .filter(r0 -> entries.stream()
                  //                                                   .anyMatch(
                  //                                                       entry -> entry.getId() == r0.getId()))
                  .map(r1 -> entries.parallelStream()
                                    .filter(entry -> entry.id() == r1.id())
                                    .findFirst()
                                    .map(elem -> new RowVsElement(r1, elem))
                                    .orElse(null))
                  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                  .forEachOrdered(pair -> saveOnMedia(pair.row, pair.element));

  }

  void saveOnMedia(Row row, Element element) {

    StringBuilder rsb = new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(row.id()));

    rsb.append(Integer.toString(row.id()));
    rsb.append(";");
    rsb.append(Integer.toString(element.id()));
    rsb.append(";");
    rsb.append(row.content());
    rsb.append(";");
    rsb.append(element.content());
    rsb.append(System.lineSeparator());

    System.out.println(rsb.toString());

  }
}
```

I've taken some print from the screen of the execution on VisualVM:

[image: Thread CPU Time]
[image: CPU Samples]
[image: Samples]
[image: Memory Heap]

Comment: For starters, replace `Random` with `ThreadLocalRandom`.

Comment: Could you post an example of execution? I see you put some print, are you sure that most of the time spent is in the stream chain operations you made in the `process()` method?

Comment: There are overlapping subproblems `new Element(...)` and `new Row(...)`, you might want to cache them using array?

Comment: Replace `StringBuilder` by `String` concatenation inside of `saveMedia` and remove `System.out.println`. Also remove the unnecessary, `Integer.toString` which is automatically done anyway

Comment: @MarcoTizzano, I've added some data from visualVM that shows what you want to know.

Comment: @Cristiano is the order important to you?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat, if I understood you. These are just samples, in the real system, they are bigger classes with more attributes.

Comment: @YassinHajaj the stream of Row is important to be kept in the order they arrived. Because they are being sorted in the Database before being processed.

Comment: Your algorithm has O(m*n) complexity – with m=235000 and n=1000000, that's ~235000000000 iterations. It might make sense to store your entries in a `HashMap<Integer, Element>` to have O(1) access by id, reducing your overall complexity to O(n) – ~1000000 iterations.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat, don't know the reason, but using `ThreadLocalRandom` have increased the execution time from 11 minutes to 23 minutes :D

Comment: @knittl, thanks. certainly, if the id where the unique property being used in the filter/map you are right. But if it isn't?

Comment: @Cristiano if it isn't, then your code example is different from the code that you want to use. Your example already finds the first item by id, so the id already has to be unique (you are using a set, so order is not deterministic)

Comment: @knittl, I use this code here to simplify things in order to ask for help. But I have a more complex Predicate instead a simple `.filter(entry -> entry.id() == r1.id())`. I don't think I could use an indexed Map...

Comment: That's strange. Anyways, I would like to point out that using an array instead of `HashMap` would be a better option here because then you don't need to box the int. I understand that the actual code is different but there are a lot of overlapping subproblems in your code. I created https://pastebin.com/SeDwKgqh for you to take a look, it runs under 1 minute on my computer.

Comment: And of course the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` can be replaced with a simple queue since you are using `forEachOrdered`.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat, indeed indexed structures are faster than anything else... but how can I get the content properties in your example then? 

The Row's content and Element's content are being created here just to simplify, but it (and other ones) comes in both source streams and I need to handle them.

Comment: The best option here is to go with the join at the database level. If we consider that the sources of the two tables are physically different then you can run some in-memory database (and populate two tables) to achieve the desired speed. If you absolutely have to use streams, then populate the array on the basis of how you want to utilize them as a predicate for eg primary key or hashcode, try to make use of locality.

Comment: Collect each stream into a list (O(n + m)). Sort each list by the ID on which you match (O(n log n) + O(m log m), so the expensive part). Process the two lists in a merge operation (O(m + n)).

Comment: @Cristiano you can always put "primary key" (i.e. the thing uniquely identifying your objects) into a its own class (which can be made up of many properties) and then provide an equals and hashCode implementation. Then use it as key in a lookup structure. As long as instantiating your key-objects or calculating its hashcode/testing for equality isn't too expensive, this should already improve things.

Comment: @OleV.V., sorry I was not able to follow your suggestion. could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the map, as people suggested:

```
Map<Integer, Element> elementMap = entries.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(it -> it.id(), it -> it, (a, b) -> a));

loadRowsData()
        //                    .filter(r0 -> entries.stream()
        //                                                   .anyMatch(
        //                                                       entry -> entry.getId() == r0.getId()))
        .map(r1 -> elementMap.containsKey(r1.id()) ? new RowVsElement(r1, elementMap.get(r1.id())) : null)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .forEachOrdered(pair -> saveOnMedia(pair.row, pair.element));
```

It should be completed in one second if you just save the result to a list, instead of printing all the result. Printing out the result may take couple of seconds.

As Knittl said in the comments: "Your algorithm has O(m*n) complexity – with m=235000 and n=1000000, that's ~235000000000". That's the reason it takes so long.